# Linking Error with Lua?

Tags: c++, linker, lua

I've got a simple test application I'm trying to build in C++ with Lua (on Linux). The build line looks like this:

```
g++ -o"LuaTest" ./src/LuaTest.o -l/home/diego/lua-5.1.4/src/liblua.a
```

And it spits out this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l/home/diego/lua-5.1.4/src/liblua.a
```

Which would be all well and good except that I'm staring liblua.a right in the face in that folder. I tried a similar configuration under Windows using MinGW and the Windows binaries for Lua and shockingly I get the exact same result, only it whines about lua51.lib or lua5.1.lib or whichever file I try.

What am I missing here?

If it matters here's the application:

```
extern "C"
{
#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"
}

int main()
{
    return 0; //this really should compile -_-
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leave out the `-l`. It should be just:

```
g++ -o"LuaTest" ./src/LuaTest.o /home/diego/lua-5.1.4/src/liblua.a
```

The `-l` switch tells g++ to automatically add the `lib` and `.a` parts of the filename, and to look for it in the standard library directories - which you don't need here.

Comment: That seems to have done it. I should have mentioned I'm using eclipse and I did in fact add this file/folder to the appropriate library paths. I guess I can't rely on that. Thanks for the tip!